# Pagination and Related Posts

Tags: posts, pagination, single

Is it possible to use pagination with the following related posts code, which is embedded in single.php of my theme.

```
    <?php
     // for use in the loop, list 5 post titles related to first tag on current post
          $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
          if ($tags) {
              $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
              $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
              $args = array(
                 'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
                 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                 'posts_per_page'=> 5,
                 'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
                 'paged'=> $paged
              );
              }
              $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                  if( $the_query->have_posts() );
                  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'content' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but might be a little complicated to apply the 'paged' variable to the arguments. You'll need pagination functions which do the ajax calls to receive and apply the 'paged' var.